# Parse Error- Syntax Error wordpress. W3 Total Cache

Tags: wordpress

I just installed "W3 Total Cache" plugin on my WordPress blog and it was working fine, but today it's giving an error:

> Parse error- syntax error, unexpected $end in /public_html/site1/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 278

What should I do now to fix it?
Here's the [blog](http://statuswish.com).

Comment: Can you provide the code in pastebin of functions.php?

Comment: You need to put your functions.php code to somewhere so we can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message would indicate the unexpected thing found in the code. To fix this issue you will have to correct the syntax in specific line number. Most of the time it is a missing bracket or some unexpected character in the code.

So as to fix the Syntax Error you should edit the code that triggered this kind of error. You can either remove it or fix the syntax.

And make sure no any extra unwanted `<?php` tag and `spaces` inside your `function.php` file.

Thanks.